# How to check if time 00:00 in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to `alert()` if this countdown timer `{{sale.vtimer | date:'mm:ss'}}` went `00:00`:

```
$scope.updateVtimerValue = function (vtimerValue){
    $.each(vtimerValue, function(k, v) {
        for (var i =0; i < $scope.sales.length ; i ++) {
            if($scope.sales[i].orderid == v.orderid){
                var nDate = Date.now();
                var nTime = Date.parse(v.xtime);
                $scope.sales[i].vtimer = nTime - nDate;
            }
        }
    });
}

<tr ng-repeat="sale in sales" ng-cloak>
   <td>{{sale.vtimer | date:'mm:ss'}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: if($scope.sales[i].vtimer.getTime() < 100)

But how often is called the updateVtimerValue function?

Comment: I set interval of 1000ms

Comment: Since you put now - value before it will always be $interval$ ms difference.Try to set nDate = Date.now() - 1 second. Or reduce the interval and check if difference is < 1sec. + you should put the interval thing in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the difference between now and previous frame is less or equal to zero, you have reached your 00 seconds

```
if($scope.sales[i].vtimer <= 0){
     alert("Timer is over");
}
```

Comment: That was helpfull. However there is no need to the interval because it is already fired before. It worked like this without getTime() since it is already in the same format: if($scope.sales[i].vtimer <= 1000){
     alert("Timer is over");
}

Comment: It launch the alert when reaching 00s or 01s? The interval is to have the alert open when reaching true 0s